# External Paramaters- Webparts- Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am trying to pass some parameters to the webpart using the following code. I am providing some default value to the same but there are not being reflected. Could anybody point me what is been missing.

```
 [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebBrowsable(true),
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebDisplayNameAttribute("Databse Name"),
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebDescriptionAttribute("Databse Name"),
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.Personalizable(
    PersonalizationScope.Shared, true),
    System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("DatabaseNameDefaultValue"),
    System.ComponentModel.CategoryAttribute("Webpart Parameters")
   ]
    public string Database
    {
        get
        {
            return _Database;
        }
        set
        {
            _Database = value;
        }
    }
```

I cannot see the default value not being assigned.

Thank you.

Hari Gillala

Comment: How are you checking for the default value ?

Comment: @Madhur: In my code I am passing the default value called databaseDefaultValue and same should be available as a default value. If I don't provide the value while using in the page then it should automatically use it.

Comment: Can you post the full code, its hard to tell without looking other parts like .webpart file and initialization code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only apply the default on brand new instances of the webpart.

And also only if the value isn't in a .webpart file that you're importing.